# JQuery css property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$("#content-container-2").css('min-height', '1000px');
$('#content-container-2').attr('style','min-height:1000px;');
```

are both not working. However, setting this via stylesheet works just fine. When using jquery with the commands mentioned above and inspecting the css-properties with firebug, they also don't show min-height was set at all. Last, but not least, printing out:

```
console.log($("#content-container-2").height());
console.log($("#content-container-2").outerHeight());
console.log($("#content-container-2").innerHeight());
```

returns null in all cases.

Does anybody know why that is?

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle? Thanks

Comment: make sure you have included Jquery script file.

Comment: Have you put your script inside `$(function () {})` ?

Comment: Please provide whole js scripts

Comment: @Sachin, I don't think it would return null. Usually it will complain about undefined function $ if jquery hasn't been included. (Chrome won't! It has a pseudo jquery function. I am not sure of other browsers.)

Comment: @john it would be better if you just share the fiddle

Comment: All other jquery related stuff works just fine, so I am pretty sure I included jquery. It is also included before this script is called, to answer any upcoming question regarding this. console.log($("#content-container-2"); also finds the div and it is inside $(function () {})

Comment: The best thing you can do is throw out jquery, write the script at the  bottom of the body and go with pure javascript.  document.getElementById('content-container-2').style["min-height"] = "1000px"

Comment: The only occassion that I know this could happen is when using multiple libraries like MooTools and jQuery simultaneously. In your case jQuery would be overridden by the later loaded library. Try and see if your code works with `jQuery('selector').css('Your code')`, though it seems not to be the problem since you said 'All other jquery related stuff works just fine'.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for `.height()` to return null is if the element is not found..

If your `#content-container-2` element is added in the page through ajax calls then you will have to run your code in the success callback of the ajax call.
(*the same could happen if you use a template engine and the template has not yet been injected in the DOM*)

You will have to make sure that `$` *belongs* to jQuery and not another library

---

For debugging try

```
var el = $('#content-container-2');
console.log( $ === jQuery, $.fn.jquery, el, el.height() );
```

Comment: I was about to ask for logging the element within the script. Logging it manually runs the code under different circumstances, creating a false impression of correctness...

Comment: @Derija93 that is what i thought too, that is why i suggest a debugging exercise that will illuminate us.. Alternatively the OP should post a live version of the page..

Comment: Can't believe I forgot that I wanted to ask for a live demo too. Though it's better for the OP to gain experience in debugging his code.

Answer (score 0):

It likely means that your jquery is not finding that particular id. Are you sure you spelled it correctly and are you sure that it isn't a class instead of id?

jQuery returns null when there are no matches.

Another consideration is that your jQuery is being called before the page is ready. To run jQuery after the page loads use the following:

```
$(function(){
     //Your code goes here.
});
```

Everything inside that code block will be executed after the page loads.

Comment: I am sure. That's why I am so confused by this. As written above, this script is called after including jquery, it is wrapped inside $(function(){...}), when i go console.log($("content-container-2")) the console prints me out the div with all it's properties, however, the style just won't apply.

Comment: Also, even if jQuery doesn't match the selector, it simply returns an empty wrapper, not `null`. [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/aquYeBI/1/)

Comment: @Derija93 It returns null after doing a select and calling a function.

Comment: If he is sure that that element exists, then those functions returning `null` must return a numeric value. Especially if the element isn't part of the DOM (in which case it wouldn't be reachable by using a selector, but let's assume it was created dynamically) `.height()` would return 0. You are correct, if the element wasn't matched those functions return `null`. But that doesn't seem to be exact case here.

Comment: @JohnSmith, I am unsure why it won't apply a style. However a workaround would be to define a class in your css that is lower in the sheet and then add that class to the container. It would then apply the styles from the sheet by class instead. Otherwise I recommend testing it with the latest jquery.

Comment: I also recommend manually adding the style to see if it can be done yourself. If the style still doesn't apply then it is something else, (bug, script, etc) that is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

To set attribute:

```
$('#content-container-2').attr('style','min-height:1000px;');
```

To Get value:

```
$('#content-container-2').attr('style');
```

If does not work check if your jquery is referenced correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify min-height in a way that javascript understands:

> `$("#content-container-2").css({'minHeight': '1000px'});`

Comment: **JavaScript syntax:**  object.style.minHeight="10px"
[http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp](W3cSchool)

Comment: that is only needed if you access it through the `style` property. Not through jQuery methods..

Comment: Try and see for your self my friend